# Excel VBA, choosing chart color based on series value comparison

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have some code I have used to color excel charts with for quite a few years and it has worked well, (although there are likely better ways to do it).  The charts contain 2 series, the first series with a value and the second with a goal.  The goal does not get colored but the vba loops through the first series and colors according to hard coded goals in the vba.

The problem I have now is that I have added a chart that has a goal that can change month to month so having the hard coding doesn't work.  How can I use the same theory but compare series 1 data directly to series 2 data to determine the color, (Case Is series 1 point > series 2 point, etc). I have tried a number of ways without success so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  below is the code for the proven technique.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim cht As Object
Dim p As Object
Dim V As Variant
Dim Counter As Integer

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
Counter = 0
V = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
For Each p In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
Counter = Counter + 1
Select Case V(Counter)

'Case Is = 1
   'p.Shadow = False
   'p.InvertIfNegative = False
   'p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
   '    Degree:=0.78
   'p.Fill.Visible = True
   'p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 5

Case Is < 0.98
    p.Shadow = False
    p.InvertIfNegative = False
    p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
        Degree:=0.78
    p.Fill.Visible = True
    p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3

'Case Is < 0.98
    'p.Shadow = False
    'p.InvertIfNegative = False
    'p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=4, _
    '    Degree:=0.38
    'p.Fill.Visible = True
    'p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 6

Case Is <= 1
    p.Shadow = False
    p.InvertIfNegative = False
    p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
        Degree:=0.78
    p.Fill.Visible = True
    p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10

End Select
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like:

`Case Is > .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)`

Also revised to get rid of some apparent redundancy (if need a loop *and* a counter variable, e.g., when looping several collections/arrays in parallel), it seems better IMO to just loop by index, rather than `For Each _object_` with a separate counter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim cht As Object
Dim p As Object
Dim V As Variant
Dim Counter As Integer

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Counter = 0
    With cht.Chart
        V = .SeriesCollection(1).Values
        For Counter = 1 to.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

            'Assign your Point object, if needed elsewhere
            Set p = .SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter)

            Select Case V(Counter)

                Case Is > .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
                'DO STUFF HERE.

                'Add other cases if needed...

            End Select
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

And unless you need the values in an array `V` for some other reason, this can be further reduced:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim cht As Object
Dim p As Object
Dim val1, val2
Dim Counter As Integer

For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Counter = 0
    With cht.Chart
        For Counter = 1 to.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

            'Assign your Point object, if needed elsewhere
            Set p = .SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter)
            ' extract specific point value to variables:
            val1 = .SeriesCollection(1).Values()(Counter)
            val2 = .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
            Select Case V(Counter)

                Case  val1 > val2
                'DO STUFF HERE.

                'Add other cases if needed...

            End Select
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: David,Thanks for the fast response.  I Made the adjustments and understand the idea but I still get a run time error.  Just to try I created a variable for the series 2 value and gave that a shot but I get the same error.

Comment: See revision: `Case Is > .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)`

Comment: Run-time error '451':  Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object

Comment: David, Thanks a ton.  I removed the variable and put it directly back to the case is and made the above change.  Works!  Thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Cheers @MattMcKenna and +1 for a good first question here on SO.

Comment: @DavidZemens I don't recall seeing something like `...Values()(Counter)` before and it's intriguing...what's that doing? Is that context only with series collections or can there be like `Range("A1").Values()(Counter)` and if so, what is it doing/how does that work?

Comment: @BruceWayne the `Values` property of `Series` object returns an array, so what it's doing there is just accessing the element by index. Yes, you can do the same thing with `_range_.Value()(_row_index, _column_index_)` but it would probably be preferable to just do `Range("A1")(_row_index_, _column_index_)`. That relies on the default value of `Range` which is `Cells` which is a Range, and returns the default property (`.Value`) of the indexed cell. It will not raise an Index out of Bounds error, either, so you can do `[A1](1,4)` to get the value from D1, etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Thanks, that's interesting!  What is that called, if I wanted to Google around and learn more? ..."Values property VBA/Excel"?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's not specific to the `Values` property of the `Series` object, nor the `Value` property of `Range` object, basically that sort of construct would work for any `object.property` that returns an array or collection. For example, you could do it with `dictionary.Keys()(_index_)` or `Worksheets()(_index_)` (but again, seems unnecessary because that's the same as `Worksheets(_index_)`.

Comment: @BruceWayne and I'm not sure why you can't directly access `series.Values(_index_)` in the same way you can access `series.Points(_index_)`, but you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Edited with final code,  The gradient needed 2 refreshes to completely fill in, (I would have to hit another tab and then go back), so I added a loop to run the code through twice and now it updates perfect the first time.  Hopefully this helps others.  This allows for a completely dynamic chart. Again, thank you David.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim cht As Object
Dim p As Object
Dim V As Variant
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim L As Integer

For L = 1 To 2

    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Counter = 0
        With cht.Chart
            V = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values
            For Counter = 1 To .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
                Set p = .SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter)

                Select Case V(Counter)

                'Blue Gradient
                    'Case Is = .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
                         'p.Shadow = False
                         'p.InvertIfNegative = False
                         'p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
                         '    Degree:=0.78
                         'p.Fill.Visible = True
                         'p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 5

                'Red Gradient
                    Case Is < .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
                        p.Shadow = False
                        p.InvertIfNegative = False
                        p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
                            Degree:=0.78
                        p.Fill.Visible = True
                        p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 3

                'Yellow Gradient
                    'Case Is < .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
                        'p.Shadow = False
                        'p.InvertIfNegative = False
                        'p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=4, _
                        '    Degree:=0.38
                        'p.Fill.Visible = True
                        'p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 6

                'Green Gradient
                    Case Is >= .SeriesCollection(2).Values()(Counter)
                        p.Shadow = False
                        p.InvertIfNegative = False
                        p.Fill.OneColorGradient Style:=msoGradientVertical, Variant:=3, _
                            Degree:=0.78
                        p.Fill.Visible = True
                        p.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 10

                End Select
            Next
        End With
    Next
Next L
End Sub
```